# java.lang.VerifyError: Bad access to protected data

Tags: groovy

I have the following Groovy file "test.groovy":

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
class Test {
  final Set<String> HISTORY = [] as HashSet

  Set<String> getHistory() {
    return HISTORY.clone() as HashSet<String>
  }
}

Test test = new Test()
println test.history
```

Compiling it with Groovy 2.4.1 works fine, however, when I run "groovy test.class" I get the following error:

```
Caught: java.lang.VerifyError: 
(class: Test, method: getHistory signature:()Ljava/util/Set;) 
Bad access to protected data  
java.lang.VerifyError: 
(class: Test, method: getHistory 
signature: ()Ljava/util/Set;) 
Bad access to protected data
at test.run(test.groovy:12)
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: it works if you are using a `final HashSet<String>` and then cast the clone up.  Since the getter overrides the property basically anyway (make it private if you wanna be sure), i'd say that would work as a workaround.

Comment: @cfrick: Thanks, your proposal works fine, feel free to post it as answer, I will accept it then. Could you please also elaborate why this is happening? I don't understand the machanics behind it.

Comment: sorry, i can't, therefor just the comment for the workaround.  the question itself, why it is happening remains open.

Comment: Just checked, and that's a bug in Groovy that you've found.  I've added it to the JIRA here http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-7325 so you can track its resolution :-)

Answer (score 1):

This actually is a bug in Groovy.  A ticket was filed: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7325

**Workaround in this case:**

It works if you are using a final `HashSet<String>` and then cast the clone up. Since the getter overrides the property basically anyway (make it `private` if you wanna be sure), it should not harm the intention of the original code.